# How to hide layer in mapbox android?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

```
   private void AddSanciangkoStreet(@NonNull Style style) {

   style.addImage("sanciangko-street",
                   BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.floodicon)));

            style.addSource(new GeoJsonSource("sanciangkoFlood1-source-id"));

            style.addLayer(new SymbolLayer("sanciangkoFlood1-layer-id", "sanciangkoFlood1-source-id").withProperties(
                    iconImage("sanciangko-street"),
                    iconIgnorePlacement(true),
                    iconAllowOverlap(true),
                    iconSize(1f)
            ));
```

I need to hide this Symbol when my statusValue = 0 and appears again when statusValue = 1. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change visibilty propery to `NONE/VISIBLE`:

```
public void updateLayer(final int statusValue) {
    mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
        @Override
        public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
            Layer layer = style.getLayer("sanciangkoFlood1-layer-id");
            if (layer != null) {
                layer.setProperties(PropertyFactory.visibility(
                        statusValue == 0 ? Property.NONE : Property.VISIBLE
                ));
            }
        }
    });
}
```